# Number format exception in parse int

Tags: java, parseint, numberformatexception

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
  String s ="12312a";
  int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
  System.out.println (x+2);
}
```

and all what I've got is :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12312a"`

any hints ?

Comment: Do you think "12312a" is a valid number ?

Comment: "12312a" its not a valid number because a is there. "12312" is integer that can parse but a is Coming Under String so you cant .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you meant

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("12312a", 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse a `String` to an `int` if the `String` isn't a number.

**eg:**

This will compile

```
String num = "3245";
int x = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

This will not:

```
String s ="12312a";
int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Remove the `a` from your `String`.

If you want to parse it to the `hexadecimal` value, use

```
int x = int x = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
```

This will parse it to base 16 number.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to parse a `String` which is not a number you get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Maybe you want to parse a hexadecimal value, then you could use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 String s ="12312a";
 int x = Integer.parseInt(s,16);
 System.out.println (x+2);
}
```

I hope it helps. Have a nice day.